# Angular retryWhen with condition statuscode

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, http-status-codes

I'm having a question with retryWhen.

I am doing a barcode scan app, the requirement is when the status code is 500, we will retry the request, if 400 then push that barcode into an array (to list the barcode with error 400).

I need to run `.retryWhen` with status code as requirement as above.
My code is now like this, but it always retry when there is an error and skip the `.subcribe`, which I need to handel error 400, I just need to retry when it's status code 500, with 400 then push that barcode into the array.

```
let modelItem = {
   ...
};
this._pickAppSv.updateTicketStatus(modelItem, !endWave)
 .retryWhen((obs) => { // Retry when error status is 500, 10 times
  return obs
   .mergeMap(error => (error.status === 500) ? Observable.throw(error) : Observable.of(error))
   .take(9);
 })
 .subscribe(
  (resp: any) => {
   ...
  },
  (err) => {
   if (err.message === 'Bad Request') { // error 400
    this.errorList.push(modelItem);
   }
  }
 );
```

I searched a lot but there did not seem to be a solution. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
this._pickAppSv.updateTicketStatus(modelItem, !endWave).pipe(
            retryWhen(obs => {
                return obs.pipe(
                    mergeMap((response) => {
                        if (response.status === 500) {
                            return of(response).pipe(
                                delay(2000),
                                take(9)
                            );
                        }
                        if (response.status == 404) {
                          //do something
                          throw({error: response});
                        }

                        return throwError({error: "Unknown error for asynchronous function:" + response});
                    }),
                );
            })
        ).subscribe({
          //do something
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for, however my rxjs version not working with ```.pipe```, so I change your code a litte bit and post an answer. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Shashank is correct. But for some reason my rxjs version cannot use with `.pipe`, so I changed it a little bit. Thank you Shashank.

```
this._pickAppSv.updateTicketStatus(modelItem, !endWave)
      .retryWhen((obs) => { // Retry when error status is 500, 10 times
        return obs
          .mergeMap((error) => {
            if (error.status === 500) {
              return Observable.of(error)
                     .delay(500)
            }
            if (error.status === 400) {
              this.errorList.push(modelItem);
              throw({error: error.message});
            }
            return Observable.throw({error: 'Error:' + error});
          })
          .take(9);
      })
      .subscribe({
        //do something
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution, to retry three times(with 2 sec delay) if error status is not 401

```
retryWhen(error => {
    return error.pipe(
        mergeMap(error => {
            if (error.status !== 401) {
                return of(error);
            }
            return throwError(error);
        }),
        scan((acc, error) => {
            if (acc > 2) throw error;
            return acc + 1;
        }, 0),
        tap((c) => console.log(`retrying ${c}`)),
        delay(2000),
    );
}),
```